# Custom Input view using Storyboard

Tags: ios7, storyboard, custom-view, inputview

I need to create a custom input view which will appear if i tap on a textfield.I have gone through [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html),but i felt it unclear,I am using storyboard also.How to achieve this using storyboards?

I have also gone through similar questions ,but couldn't find a way to achieve the above using storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

few months back I made a application with farsi keyboard.

here is a sample app I uploaded on github. Download and run, hope it helps.

[Custom keypad sample application using a protocol](https://github.com/vikysaran/Application)